# Change javascript variable on the fly from external source

Tags: javascript

I have two files data1.js and data2.js
data1.js has a variable like

```
var rows = ['g1', 'g2'];
```

data2.js has a variable like

```
var rows = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4'];
```

Initially, I am loading data1.js using

```
<script id="datascript" type="text/javascript" src="data1.js"></script>
```

However, on a button click I am loading data2.js with the hope of it loading its contents (i.e. updating the variable rows):

```
onclick="datascript.src='data2.js';alert(rows);"
```

However, my rows variable does not update. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Insert a new `<script>` element, just changing the url of an existing one does not work (at least not in all browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to read the value of the `rows` variable *before* the second JS file is download and executed by your browser. To solve this:

Use `jQuery.getScript()` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ - which provides a callback *after* the script is downloaded and executed.

**Code**:

```
$('#datascript').remove();
$.getScript("data2.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   alert(rows);
});
```

Or, if you wan to stick with pure JS, you can do:

Ref: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

```
// remove previous script element
var sElem = document.getElementById('datascript')
sElem.parentNode.removeChild(sElem);

// insert new script
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.id = 'datascript';
newScript.onload= function() {
   alert(rows);
};
newScript.src = 'data2.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me XMLHttpRequest cannot load PATH-TO-DATA/data2.js?_=1348997881471. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin...

Comment: Assuming data2.js is from the same server, you can give the full path to the js file relative to your document root. Pls check updated code above.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I've put in some code to remove the previous script element each time a new one is put in. NOTE that this does not erase any functions etc.. defined by the previous instance. It only removes the script element from the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! JS solution worked perfectly for me. I think the jquery solution will work too, but I did some research and Chrome wont let me choose local files (i.e. my code would have to be on a server to avoid  XMLHttpRequest error)